# normalized compression distance C code

Tags: c, compression, distance, normalize

does anybody knows if there is already a code in C that calculates the NCD (normalized compression distance) for two files or I need to write the code by myself? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there are any C libraries out there to compute the NCD family of functions or anything of the sort. Your best bet might be to do this in `MATLAB` and then convert the `m files` into equivalent `C` code as a `mex file`. Alternatively, you could write your own code too.

If your code can run on Linux systems, then you can use the `tar` utility with `-z` option for `gzip` and `-j` option for the `bzip` compression algorithm. To create a `bzip` archive, use the following option: `tar -cjf foo.bz2 temp/` creates a `bzip` archive of the `temp/` directory and names the output `foo.bz2`. To create a `gzip` archived file, use the following options: `tar -cjf foo.gzip temp/`

To call this code from within a `c` program, you can use the `system()` command. This command takes whatever utility you want to invoke (with parameters) as a string as input and returns an `int` indicating success or failure. You can invoke it like so:

```
int i = system("tar -cjf foo.bz2 temp/")
```

Comment: good point thank you! my code should be able to run in any machine (Linux, Windows etc)..so how can i use the compression algorithm (like gzip, zlib, bzip2 etc) inside my code? any idea on that?

Comment: or also the kolmogorov complexity as compressor

Comment: thank you for you answer again! i had this on my mind but it should run on Windows too, so how can i do that on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `ncd` under Ubuntu Hardy Heron. It may be what you're looking for. Further info: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ncd.1.html

EDIT:
The `ncd` program comes from the `libcomplearn` package and you can download this package (the sources are in a folder called `src`) from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+source/libcomplearn/1.1.1-1

Please note that I haven't taken a look at the licensing terms and other limitations of the tool. You might want to have a look at them before using the tool or the sources.